# Youtube API, can I query videos filtering out channels?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am writing queries to the Youtube Data v3 API and I want to see a list of videos that don't include videos by a certain channel. For example, a keyword search "iPhone" but not by Apple's channel. It doesn't work if I just do "-Apple" because that is filtering out the keyword versus the channel. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using as the query `'"iPhone" -Apple"'` removes all videos containing Apple ([source](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/117773516?msgid=117795469)), so it removes more than what you want but it does the job.

By the way [Apple only uploaded 202 public videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUE_M8A5yxnLfW0KghEeajjw) as of today, so you could just exclude their channel id ([UCE_M8A5yxnLfW0KghEeajjw](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCE_M8A5yxnLfW0KghEeajjw)) from the results you got with [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

Comment: Unfortunately for me, the channel name I need to exclude is the exact same as the keyword, but I excluded the channel ID as a keyword and that worked

Comment: I tested by excluding the channel id but on the YouTube UI I got a result from the given YouTube channel...